# Rank of Sets and Hierarchy of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to learn set theory from a book, **Elements of Set Theory** by Herbert Enderton.  His book has some practice exercises and I was hoping you could help me determine if I understand them and, if not, where I went wrong.

1. Define the rank of a set c to be the least "a" such that c ⊆ Va (where Va is the general notation he uses for each iteration in a hierarchy of sets).  Compute the rank of {{∅}}.  Compute the rank of {∅,{∅},{∅,{∅}}}

Answer:  V0 = ∅.  V1 = V0 ⋃ P(V0) = {∅,{∅}}.  V2 = V1 ⋃ P(V1) = {∅,{∅},{{∅}},{∅,{∅}}}.  Therefore, {{∅}} is rank 1 and {∅,{∅},{∅,{∅}}} is rank 2.

2. We (the author) have stated that Va+1 = A ⋃ P(Va) (where A = ∅).  Prove this for at least a < 3.

Answer:  I'm not sure how to prove this except using the kind of expansion I tried to do above??

Please let me know if I have misunderstood, the text is fairly concise and well-written but not simple to grasp when trying to learn it on my own.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prove by induction that for all natural numbers $\alpha$, $V_\alpha \subseteq P(V_\alpha)$.

For $\alpha = 0$, this is trivial since $V_\alpha = \emptyset$.

For $\alpha = \beta + 1$, we see that $V_\alpha = V_\beta \cup P(V_\beta) = P(V_\beta)$. Since $V_\beta \subseteq V_\alpha$, we have $V_\alpha = P(V_\beta) \subseteq P(V_\alpha)$.

Note that you can extend this to all ordinals $\alpha$ by doing ordinal induction. We need only add the following clause:

For $\alpha$ a limit ordinal, we see that $V_\alpha = \bigcup\limits_{\beta < \alpha} V_\beta \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\beta < \alpha} P(V_\beta) \subseteq P(\bigcup\limits_{\beta < \alpha} V_\beta) = P(V_\alpha)$.